# What is the difference between the BSD and the BCL licenses?

Tags: licensing, bsd-license, bcl

What differences are there, if any, between BSD and BCL licences?

Comment: Were you referring to the Binary Code License?  If so, I think I should probably delete my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @jmort yes, the Binary Code License

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)

The BSD is significantly smaller than the BCL. The BSD has the typical "as-is" disclaimer and requires that the license be re-distributed with the software and source. In addition, it also places restrictions on advertisement and endorsements. The BSD allows for modifications of software. The BSD is intended for both source and binary code.

### [BCL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/jdk-1_5_0-license.txt)

The BCL is significantly larger and far more restrictive. It is not intended for source code but rather for [Binary Code](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/source_license.html). The JDK binary is under the BCL. It does not allow for modifications nor redistribution of source (if any is provided). It does allow for redistribution of the binary but with strict compliance, as outlined in the "README" file.

The JDK source is available under the Sun Community Source License ([SCSL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/source_license.html)) and also the Java Research License ([JRL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/jrl_5.0-license.txt)). The JRL license is fairly straightforward and easy to understand. The limitation of the JRL does not permit modification for commercial use and distribution use. The SCSL does allow for commercial modifications, but it has several restrictions and is difficult to follow.

Comment: /striaght/straight/s